# phpstormからguiでcomposer install, composer updateする方法

Tags: php, phpstorm

タイトルのとおりですが、phpstorm8で`composer install`, `composer update`に相当する操作をするにはどうしたらいいのでしょうか？

メニューの`Tool` -> `Composer`には`init Composer`と`Add dependency`しかなく毎回install, updateする時だけターミナルから実行しています。

Answer (score 1):

GUIからできるのは、composer.jsonの作成（init Composer）とパッケージの追加（Add dependency）だけのようです。"Add dependency" はターミナルで言うところの`require`コマンドなります。

> $ composer require ベンダー名/パッケージ名:バージョン

GUIの方がキーワードで検索した後に、パッケージとバージョンを選択できるので、分かりやすいです。

composerの最も多い操作は、パッケージを追加して行く作業なので、GUIでカバーするのはこれだけで良いという考えではないでしょうか？

[PhpStormの公式サイト](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/using-composer-dependency-manager.html)では、composerの全てのコマンドを使うなら、Ctrl+Shift+Xを使ってコマンドラインウィンドウを使うようにと書かれていました。コマンドの補完が効くようですが、ターミナルを使うのとさほど変わりません。

参考サイト
http://qiita.com/pakiln/items/22f4b86501f78a21d34f
https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/using-composer-dependency-manager.html

ここからは、質問の文章からの推測になりますが、パッケージを追加する時に、composer.jsonに追記してから、updateしたりしてますか？もしそうだとすると、この操作は誤りです。このやり方だと、追記したパッケージ以外の物が、意図せずバージョンアップしてしまい、プログラムが動かなくなる可能性があります。パッケージを追加したいだけなら、composer.jsonに追記をせずに、requireコマンドを使うのが正しいやり方です。